# Designing One-To-One Relationships

Tags: database-design, schema, relations

To begin with, I have to admit that I don't have great experience in designing database schemas. Being influenced by OOP , I find that by dividing the info we have about a object into different entities, we achieve better info organization.

For example , let's say we have a basketball player. For each player we have some **general info** like their name , their age , the position they play etc. We also have some info about **their performance during his whole career** (eg total points scored , total blocks etc). It is obvious that the relation between a player and their lifetime stats is **1:1**.

Let's see some designing options for this relation now:

- The most simple option would be to include the player's general info with their stats in a single table. But this seems to unorganized to me ; let's just imagine that we have more than 50 columns for the stats.
- The second option would be to create a table player_stats and have as primary key the player_id and referencing through it the primary key of the players table. I think that is called **One-To-One Bidirectional** relationship.

[image: One-To-One Undirectional]

- The third option would be to make put a foreign key in the player referncing his stats. That would be a **One-To-One Undirectional** relationship.

[image]

- The fourth option is to make a join table combining both info. Placing unique constraints ensures that there will be no duplicates of a player or of a stat.

[image]

So let's summarize. **Is it a good idea to break information to different tables? And if yes, what design should be preffered in One-To-One relationships and when ?**

Comment: It doesn't make sense to store `age`, as it changes over time. Store date of birth instead.

Comment: @mustaccio Good catch , but let's not stick to this particular example. It is used only as a means to the real question.

Comment: It just shows that you haven't thought your model through. I'm not sure how "real" is your real question. "Being influenced by OOP", is "player_stats" an object in your model? Why?

Comment: @mustaccio player_stats is a somehow different entity from the player itself. It describes the performance of a player not the player as a person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1

This is the preferred design under most circumstances.

## Option 2 & 3

From experience, try to stay away from splitting the data.  I did it in one application but realized (after a few years) that it was doing more harm (programming wise) than good.

The only time this method makes sense is with an "IS A" type relationship design.

eg: The proper way to store a player's stats for a player like Michael Jordon would be to have `BASKETBALL_STATS`,`BASEBALL_STATS`, and `GOLF_STATS` tables.  Each one "IS A" type of `STATS`.

### unidirectional

For maintaining unidirectional, foreign key from the `STATS` table to the `PLAYERS` table is needed.

### bidirectional

For bidirectional, you would also need an FK from the `PLAYERS` table to the `STATS` table that is validated at `COMMIT` time instead of DML time ( `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` for Oracle).

This gets a little complicated when you have multiple types of Stats.

## Option 4

I would use this design if and only if the `STATS` data is a [Slowly Changing Dimension (SCD) Type 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) data.  Under that design, you are actually storing the history of a player's stats as games/years progress.

**EDIT** As I think about it, this model doesn't even make sense for this scenario.  Instead, you'd have a nullable FK in the `PLAYERS` table that points to the most recent row in the `STATS` table.  You'll update that column with the correct information within the same transaction as the new stats information.

Comment: Amazing answer, gave me food for thought

Answer (score 0):

No. There's nothing unorganized having 50 columns of statistics, if they are normalized.   But these columns may contain redundant information, if details are available concerning the player's career.

Comment: Let's assume that there are details like percentages or mean values. How can we distinguish what is reduntant and what is not.

Comment: If you can calculate them, they are redundant.   You could still store them, for performance reasons.